# td height and width not getting picked up

Tags: html

I am working on a html email signature but I would like to change an td its height and width here is the code:

```
<tr bgcolor="#ffd668" style="height: 50px;">
    <td colspan="10" style="border-radius: 5px;">
        <table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td width="5"></td>
                <td width="200" height="30" align="left" style="line-height: 0" colspan="2">
                    <a style="border: 0;" href="https://www.fingerspitz.nl" target="_blank">
                        <img width="128" height="22" alt="Fingerspitz" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/Fingerspitz_logo.png">
                    </a>
                </td>

                <td width="190" align="right">
                    <table style="width:100%;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td width="30" height="30">
                                <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px; height: 30px;" href="https://www.facebook.com/Fingerspitz" target="_blank">
                                    <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/80_x_80/LinkedIn.png\">
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td width="30" height="30">
                                <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px; height: 30px;" href="https://twitter.com/fingerspitzNL/" target="_blank">
                                    <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/80_x_80/Twitter.png">
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td width="30" height="30">
                                <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px; height: 30px;" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/fingerspitz" target="_blank">
                                    <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/80_x_80/LinkedIn.png">
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td width="40" height="30">
                                <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px; height: 30px;" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpovXRL4rEF8skjhle2z25Q" target="_blank">
                                    <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/80_x_80/YouTube.png">
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td width="0.2" height="20" bgcolor="#00000"></td>
                            <td width="40" height="30" align="right">
                                <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px; height: 30px;" href="https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Fingerspitz+Online+Marketing/@51.5904415,4.7595442,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c69f8ba6d2e709:0xbbf458d8e81294cb!8m2!3d51.5904382!4d4.7617329" target="_blank">
                                    <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/80_x_80/Maps.png">
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td width="15" height="30"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the html code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fk4r2js9/)

So basically what I would like to achieve is that the vertical black stripe between the youtube and googlemaps icon is a little bit thinner and the height is even with the icon image.

Could someone help me out on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check now

```html
<tr bgcolor="#ffd668" style="height: 50px;">
  <td colspan="10" style="border-radius: 5px;">
   <table>
    <tbody><tr>
     <td width="5"></td>
     <td width="200" height="30" align="left" style="line-height: 0" colspan="2">
      <a style="border: 0;" href="https://www.fingerspitz.nl" target="_blank">
       <img width="128" height="22" alt="Fingerspitz" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/Fingerspitz_logo.png">
      </a>
     </td>

     <td width="190" align="right">
      <table style="width:100%;">
       <tbody><tr>
        <td width="30" height="30">
         <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px; height: 30px;" href="https://www.facebook.com/Fingerspitz" target="_blank">
          <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/80_x_80/LinkedIn.png">
         </a>
        </td>
        <td width="30" height="30">
         <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px; height: 30px;" href="https://twitter.com/fingerspitzNL/" target="_blank">
          <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/80_x_80/Twitter.png">
         </a>
        </td>
        <td width="30" height="30">
         <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px; height: 30px;" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/fingerspitz" target="_blank">
          <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/80_x_80/LinkedIn.png">
         </a>
        </td>
        <td width="40" height="30">
         <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px; height: 30px;" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpovXRL4rEF8skjhle2z25Q" target="_blank">
          <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/80_x_80/YouTube.png">
         </a>
        </td>
        <td width="0.2" height="30"  ><span style="background-color:#000;height:28px;display:table;width:2px;"></span></td>
        <td width="40" height="30" align="right">
         <a style="border: none; display: block; width: 30px; height: 30px;" href="https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Fingerspitz+Online+Marketing/@51.5904415,4.7595442,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c69f8ba6d2e709:0xbbf458d8e81294cb!8m2!3d51.5904382!4d4.7617329" target="_blank">
          <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.fingerspitz.nl/files/Social_iconen/80_x_80/Maps.png">
         </a>
        </td>
        <td width="15" height="30"></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody></table>

     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody></table>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: But the vertical line is not the same height as the image, they have to align horizontal. Do you know how to achieve this because i cant change the height.

Comment: It is bigger than the icons how can I achieve this to be the same height?

Comment: it's perfect now please check and revert back if any other changes you required.